# JavaScript Patch-work error

Tags: javascript

I am using sales force platform but it is a Javascript problem. I have a button and on click this button should[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWlXS.png) check a check box and a **pop up** should appear. It works fine but sometimes it gives me an error. I am attaching the console here. Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some code on page is failing to fetch some picture; this picture is probably used on the popup, but without picture patch-worker.js could not create some elements within a popup, and that stops popup creation.

To fix this, you probably need to change the link to some other (existing) picture.

That's all I can tell from screenshot you provided.